# Ratio of segments in equally divided triangle

Tags: geometry, area

> In a $\Delta PQR$, $M$ and $N$ are points on $PQ$ and $PR$, respectively such that $MN || QR$ and $MN$ divides $\Delta PQR$ into two parts equal in area, then find the ratio of $PM:PQ$.

[image]

Let '$[...]$' denote the area of a polygon. Then $[PNM]=[NMQR]=x$.

Joining $RM$, we see that $$\frac{PM}{PQ-PM}=\frac{[PNM]+[MNR]}{[NMQR]-[MNR]}=\frac{x+[MNR]}{x-[MNR]}$$

$$\frac{PM}{PQ-PM}=\frac{PN}{PR-PN}=\frac{[PNM]}{[MNR]}=\frac{x}{[MNR]}$$

Let $\frac{PM}{PQ-PM}=y$, then $$y=\frac{x+\frac1y}{x-\frac1y}$$

I am not able to proceed further from here except for simplifying the above equation. Help?

Comment: Actually I miswrote a '-' sign as a '+' (not on purpose!). I'll leave the question up for any students who are interested in solving it or finding the mistake..

Answer (score 1):

We can use similar triangles. Let $\triangle PMN \sim \triangle PQR$ with similarity ratio $r$. Then we know
$$\frac{[PMN]}{[PQR]} = r^2 = \frac{1}{2} $$
$$\Rightarrow r=\frac{PM}{PQ}=\ldots$$

Comment: I at least used a variable name different than yours - $k$ vs. $r$ :) :)

Comment: Sorry about that :) There is an interesting question I have to share, when I get on PC